# ¿Como puedo editar un input, sin enviar formulario y hacer cálculos correspondientes?

Tags: javascript, html-tabla

Tengo problema que lo pedido es poder editar los inputs sin necesidad de enviar el formulario, no se como hacer para que lo que ingrese en los campos inputs, se haga una división sin necesidad de enviar el formulario.
Lo intente con json para almacenar los valores pero debe ser como un tabla de excel, GRACIAS

El codigo:

```
<tr>
            <td rowspan="">PRODUCTO-CIBER SEGURIDAD ON PREMISE</td>
            <td rowspan="9">Security-Firewall (Cisco Meraki, Fortinet)</td>
            <td>AntimalWare Perimetral</td>
            <td>FIREWALL</td>
            <?php
                            $datos = file_get_contents("controller/datos.json");
                            $json = json_decode($datos, true);
                            foreach ($json as $json_array):
                                ?>
            <td><input type="number"></td>
            <td><input type="number"></td>
            <td><?php echo $json_array['total']; ?></td>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar jQuery, es una biblioteca  que te permite realizar acciones **POST, GET, etc** sin necesidad de hacer un call back o refrescar la página.
Te dejo un ejemplo sencillo de dividir para 2 el número que ingresas en el input **valor** y lo muestras en el input **resultado**

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type = "text" id = "valor" name = "valor">
    <input type = "text" id = "resultado" name = "resultado">
</body>
</html>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#valor").change(function() {         
        var res =  $("#valor").val() / 2;
        $("#resultado").val(res);
   }); 
});
```

De igual manera te dejo el link de JSFiddle para que veas el funcionamiento del código.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wj5q7crt/)